# final field in class initialized from application.properties

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Is it possible to initialize final field from `application.properties` file ?
I am using spring 4. If not, is there any way to do it ?
`defaulValue` in spring controllers requires final value, however I would like to read it from configuration file.

Answer (score 2):

You need constructor injection to set final values:

```
@Component
public class MyController {

    private final String prop;

    @Autowired
    public MyController(@Value("${some.prop}") String prop) {
        this.prop = prop;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you explain me what does it mean `@Autowired` above constructor ? So far I have used only it in connection with fields.

Comment: Autowired just tells Spring it needs to inject the parameter values. You can also set it on setters for example. If you set the autowired annotation on a constructor you can e.g. do extra validation such as null checks, compared to a situation where you have the annotation on a field. It's pretty well documented in the Spring documentation.

Comment: you dont need the @Autowired annotation on the constructor anymore as per the latest version.